# How to use Categories of custom post type

Tags: posts, customization

On my website psychscenehub.com I have Custom Post Type setup. Just Like the WordPress default Post section, I can see the categories on Custom Posts, but I don't know how to use them to display on my site.

For example, I can add a widget of categories via `Appearance > Widgets` but I can only see the categories of default Post Type there and not the Custom Post.

Please let me know if I need to provide any further information?

Website URL: psychscenehub.com

Comment: Search google for "custom taxonomy widget plugins" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include them in a widget then there's a plugin for that. 
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/